# Find clicked div angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I simply want to find the clicked div with using a directive and what I have tried:

```
.directive('blocks', blocks);

  function blocks(){
     var linkFunc;
     linkFunc = function(scope,element,attrs){
         element.bind('click', function(){
         //assign clicked div
         var selectedDiv = $(this);
         if(selectedDiv.hasClass('block1')){
         console.log('block1 is clicked!');
         }        
       });
     };
  return{
      restrict: 'E',
      link: linkFunc, 
      template: '<div class="block block1 block_unactive">DIV 1</div>' +
        '<div class="block block2 block_unactive">DIV 2</div>' +
        '<div class="block block3 block_unactive">DIV 3</div>' +
        '<div class="block block4 block_unactive">DIV 4</div>'
    };
  };
```

that doesn't work.. How can I assign the clicked div as selectedDiv?

For Exp: On click a div; check the click div and if the clicked div hasClass 'block1' do block1 actions.. if the div hasClass 'block2' do block2 actions... etc..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why are you doing this with jQuery when you can use `ng-click`?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. Do you want to click any block and have it say what number it is? Are there always 4 blocks?

Comment: Because I have to do more manipulations and this is the base point.. I thought that it would be more clear using directive link function instead of ng-click..

Comment: I updated the question, I hope its more clear now...

Answer (score 0):

i've another way to handle issue like that, passing div number to a service which will apply the desired action.

we have three files

the view  `index.html`

```
  <section ng-controller="BlockController as block">
    <ul>                
            <li ng-class="{ selected: block.isSet(1) }">
            <a href ng-click="block.setTab(1)">Block 1</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{ selected: block.isSet(2) }">
            <a href ng-click="block.setTab(2)">Block 2</a></li>
             ...........
    </ul>
  </section>
```

the controller `main.js`

```
    var app = angular.module('mainApp', ["ServicesModule"]);    
    app.controller('BolckController',["service",function("service"){
    this.block = 1;

    this.setBlock = function(newValue){
      this.block = newValue;
      //service is defined in servicesModule.js
      service.doBlockAction(newValue);
    };

    this.isSet = function(blockName){
      return this.block === blockName;
    };
  }
 ] );
```

the service `servicesModule.js`

```
var ServiceApp = angular.module('ServicesModule', []);

ServiceApp.factory('service', function() {
    var doAction=function(BlockName){
     if(BlockName === 1)
   {
    console.log('block1 is clicked!');
     }else{if(BlockName === 2)}
       console.log('block2 is clicked!');
         };
    return {
        doBlockAction : function(blockName) {
         return doAction(blockName);
        }
    }
});
```

I dont test the syntax but the logic make sense to work properly
i hope it helps